# Sci fi humor/adventure book with people renting bodies in an intergalactic cruise ship, main character gets an assassin's body

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this sci-fi book quite some time ago, it was an old paperback, and I can only remember parts of it.

Most of the story takes place on some sort of intergalactic cruise ship and for some reason relevant to the plot, people rent/change bodies for the travel.

The main character is an “average Joe” who accidentally ends up with some super soldier/assassin body instead of the one he was supposed to get, leading to high jinks and mayhem.

Comment: Can you can give us a figure — even a very rough estimate — for how many years ago you read it? That would help narrow the possibilities further.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thanks so much, it definitely was Starfall, I’ll try to phrase and format my questions better next time, honestly amazing what folks can do with such little information, like Sherlock Holmes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [*Star Fall*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2490295.Starfall) by David Bischoff from 1980?

The space-traveling cruise ship certainly matches (though it was interstellar vs. intergalactic). So does the body swapping (snippet below).

If it is *Star Fall* then it appears to be a duplicate of the following:  [Brain swapping, alien conspiracy, space cruise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112247/looking-for-book-brain-swapping-alien-conspiracy-space-cruise)

> It reads like the author wanted to do some musing on the mind-body connection, so he just straightforwardly incorporated that into the story before there was even a story. We’re introduced to two characters – Philip Amber and Todd Spigot – who are opposites physically and mentally and, through circumstances that aren’t that well-explained and clearly there for the convenience of the plot, end up having their brains implanted in bodies that belong to the other. Note the wording there – it isn’t clear that the body that Philip Amber starts the story in is his original. He seems to have been doing the manner of body-hopping for a long time. Todd Spigot’s body is the one he was born with, though, and one of the more interesting points in the book is the changes it goes through while inhabited by a fitter mind. As the story progresses, we run the rest of the gamut – there are disembodied brains, cyborgs, collective minds, and human-alien hybrids.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this.  I agree. This could be construed as confusing. The OP had the terminology as intergalactic when it should have been interstellar.  A common enough mistake.  I have edited the answer to note the difference.  The key thing being that it was a space traveling cruise liner.